# Windows 8 why Norton alert: "unauthorized access blocked" WMIPRVSE.exe?

Tags: alert, norton-360

When checking the security history in Norton 360 I see that Norton has flagged a medium alert:

> Unauthorized access blocked (Access Process Data). The date is
>   9/15/2015, Actor: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM\WMIPRVSE.exe and the
>   Target: C:\Program Files(x86)\Norton 360\Engine\22.5.2.15\N360.exe and
>   Action: Access Process Data and Reaction: Unauthorized access blocked.

What is `WMIPRVSE.exe` doing that causes Norton to block it and create this alert?

Comment: [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) congratulations Norton discovered and identified system file you installed and enabled as a Trojan, falsely identified, thus completely a useless notification.

Answer (score 0):

It a log entry for '[Norton Product Tamper Protection](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v45039218_N360_Security_CC_2014_en_us?)' which is responsible for securing Norton product's files/processes/threads/modules from being accessed/modified/erased by an external application/modules.

Its not a sign of infection in your case as the application trying to gain access is a Windows program. You can safely ignore the warning.